# SQL Server Windows Authentication issue

Tags: sql-server

I tried to find any solution for this but I was unable to find it.

Basically what I have is:

- SQL Server on Server Machine -> I can connect using SQL Server Authentication and Windows Authentication
- SQL Server from my client machine -> I can connect using SQL Server Authentication but I **can't** connect using Windows Authentication.

It's quite weird. I tried to use SQL Profiler but nothing, looks like it's not even reaching SQL Server

I tried Event Viewer and nothing there.

When trying to connect using Windows Authentication I get the following error:

> ### TITLE: Connect to Database Engine
>
> Cannot connect to 99.99.99.99.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while
>   attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This
>   could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was
>   unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting
>   to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=18970;
>   handshake=14931;  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-2&LinkId=20476
>
> ---
>
> The wait operation timed out

Some Info:

- The server and Client are connected to the same network and same Domain.
- The Client machine is connected via VPN
- The Windows Authentication is over a Domain User
- The Domain user is setup correctly on SQL Server
- When on the Server, via terminal services, I can connect using Windows Authentication but not from my client machine.

Does anyone knows what could be this issue?

**UPDATE**

I still have this issue in place, but we were able to narrow down the problem and seems to be on the VPN. For some reason the VPN is messing up with the Windows Authentication.

Comment: Is  TCP/IP enabled for both the IPv4 address, and for the IPv6 address of the server?

Comment: I confirm only IPv4. IPv6 is not enabled on the server. It is indeed enabled on my client machine.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/659840/cant-connect-to-local-sql-server-while-connected-to-a-vpn ?

Comment: it does not seem to be a routing problem. I can connect to sql server from my client machine using a SQL Server user. Network should not be the problem. The problem is only if I try to use Windows Authentication. Anyway, the routing table looks gibberish to me.